# Pushing Objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, express

All, I am attempting to push objects into an array and console.logging the new array to see what it looks like, and it appears as if it is not working correctly.  Can you please tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

```
<% var testObjArray = [] %>    
<% var testObj = {} %>

<% currentUser.shares.forEach(function(share){ %>
    <% if(!share || share.length < 1){ %>
    <!--DO NOTHING-->
    <% } else { %>
        <% if(currentUser.id == share.yes_owner.id){ %>
            <% testObj.price = share.event.yes_purchase_price %>
            <% testObj.yes_or_no = "YES" %>

        <% } else { %>

            <% testObj.price = share.event.no_purchase_price %>
            <% testObj.yes_or_no = "No" %>
        <% }%>
            <% testObj.quantity = 1 %>
            <% testObj.eventId = share.event.id %>
            <% testObj.name = share.event.name %>

        <% testObjArray.push(testObj) %>
        <% console.log(testObj) %>
    <% }%>
<% }) %>
<% console.log("THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: " + testObjArray) %>
```

I want the end result to be and was expecting it to be..

```
[{ price: undefined,
  yes_or_no: 'No',
  quantity: 1,
  eventId: 588a107edf666e0273614cca,
  name: 'Will this work?' },
{...}, 
{...},
{ price: undefined,
  yes_or_no: 'No',
  quantity: 1,
  eventId: 588a107edf666e0273614cca,
  name: 'Will this work?' }
...]
```

However, it turned out like...

"THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: " [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: you (also) have one fatal flaw in your code, the fact that you will be overwriting the testObj in every iteration, meaning your array will end up with the same object (the *last* one) multiple times, rather than a new object in each slot - you need to put `var testObj = {}` **inside the forEach loop**

Comment: also, what is this <% %> on ever line? can't you put <% on the first line, and %> on the last?

Comment: I guess so.. I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
console.log("THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: " + testObjArray)
```

to

```
console.log("THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: ", testObjArray)
```

Because `"string" + Object` makes Objects printed as strings

Answer (score 1):

You are logging out the object references, to log out a string of the object keys and values you can call `JSON.stringify()` on your object:

```
<% console.log("THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: " + JSON.stringify(testObjArray)) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log()` is causing an implicit call `toString()` on the object because you are concatenating it with a string.

You can pass n arguments to `console.log()`, so changing the

```
console.log("THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: " + testObjArray)
```

to

```
console.log("THIS IS THE NEW OBJARRAY: ", testObjArray);
```

will give you the output you expected.